# The app crashes every time i open it. I think that the probable error may be that sub_http remains empty while custom adapter fetches it.

Tags: android, firebase

The app crashes every time i open it. I think that the probable error may be that sub_http remains empty while custom adapter fetches it. 
how to wait while firebase data s loaded completely.**strong text**

```
package com.bansh.barcelonavsrealmadrid;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener;
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.Map;

public class custom extends AppCompatActivity {

    String get_http;
    String get_name;
    String[] sub_name;
    String[] sub_http;
    Firebase mref;
    int h=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom);

        Intent intent=getIntent();


        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        mref=new Firebase("https://fcbvsreal11-9d1f9.firebaseio.com/");



        mref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Map<String,String> map=dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
                get_name=map.get("Barca ");
                get_http=map.get("Barca_Images");


                sub_name=get_name.split(",");
                sub_http=get_http.split(",");







            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

        Intent ne=getIntent();
        ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.barca_list_new);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter();
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    }

    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {


            return sub_http.length;

        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.new_custom,null);
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);



            Picasso.with(custom.this).load(sub_http[position]).into(imageView);

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which error message do you get? In which line is it crashing? Some more information would be useful.

Comment: see the problem is that get_http is retrieving data from firebase , but i think it take soome time to load and at the same time Custom class is retrieving the length of sub_http which is empty at that time. Now what i want , is there any method by which i can pause the execution to load the firebase data first and then it do next work

Comment: of course you can pause the application, but that would not be very user friendly. If I were you i would run the stuff in an async task and set the values in the onPostExecute method.